# Rename directory name having junk characters in AIX

Tags: rename

4000 - LCL**\010**PL CPS Test Bank A

directory name having some junk chars as shown above and I am unable to rename it and unable to go neither  inside this directory nor copy contents

Please help me to rename directory name having junk in AIX/UNIX server

Answer (score 0):

Use some script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$@"; do
    To="$(printf '%s' "$i" | tr '\n\r' '_' | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.-_]/_/g')"
    mv -- "$i" "$To"
done
```

When call it, use a file-mask as parameter, eg:

```
./myscript *LCL*
```